# Write this ODE without any square roots

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Given the function $$u(t):=\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i t^{2i}}$$

is it possible to plug this into the ODE 
$$(t^2-1)u''(t)+tu'(t)(1-8a+8at^2)-4(a+a^2-2at^2+n(-a+2at^2)-C)u(t)=0 $$

such that I get a linear equation for the coefficients $\alpha_i$? I really loose track doing this or run into a lot of exponents.

Comment: I don't think so. I tried evaluating it with Mathematica and the left-hand side simplifies to $p/u(t)^3$ where $p$ is quadratic in the $\alpha_i$.

Comment: would you mind posting your result? I mean it is still the answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica tells me that $u(t)^3$ times your left-hand side is
$$-4 \left(a^2+a (n-1) (2 t^2-1)-c\right) \left(\sum _{i=0}^n \alpha_i t^{2 i}\right)^2 \\
+\frac12 \left(\sum _{i=0}^n \alpha_i t^{2 i}\right) \left(t \left(8 a (t^2-1)+1\right) \sum _{i=0}^n 2 i \alpha_i t^{2 i-1}+(t^2-1) \sum _{i=0}^n 2 i (2 i-1) \alpha_i t^{2 i-2}\right) \\
-\frac14(t^2-1) \left(\sum _{i=0}^n 2 i \alpha_i t^{2 i-1}\right)^2,$$
so assuming $u(t)$ is nonzero you get a quadratic equation in the $\alpha_i$.

Comment: By the way, when posting the answer I tweaked the $\LaTeX$ output a bit to make it more readable; I don't think I introduced any errors but you should validate it numerically just in case.